# Submenu in a tableview controller

Tags: ios, ios5

I'm creating my first app for iOS, and I need something like a submenu for showing data for specific dates, one just like in the last image of the TextHog app http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/texthog/id343405995?mt=8. The menu under the Navigation controller where u can switch between months. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: By "submenu", do you mean "detail" view? That is by selecting a cell in your table view, you navigate to detail view showing detailed data?

Comment: You probably want to add sections to your tableview, this is easily accomplished with the UITableViewDelegate methods described in the apple docs

Comment: Not really, see the last picture of the TextHog app (from the link in my question) i don't know how to put the green bar in the "Expences" tableview (currently set on December 2009) i want that to be static, while i switch between different months.

Answer (score 0):

Use UISegmentedControl to make it look like TextHog. You can use it inside and outside tableviewCell. This question may help. [How to use UISegmentedControl with UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110292/how-to-use-uisegmentedcontrol-with-uitableview)

Comment: It may work, but won't look appropriate, I'm getting data (dates variables) from a CoreData database, and i need to shift according the different dates.  So if i have 20 different dates it will need to put 20 segments on the Segmented control. I need something like a bar where i will just shif left-right

Comment: Then use one scrollview with required buttons (custom type with background image) will solve your problem :)